# Ubuntu 14.04 detects my monitor as a built in display

Tags: display, screen

I just started using Linux and I literally know nothing about it. The current resolution is at 1024x768 and the other option is to change it to 800x 600. My monitor is 1920x1080. It also detects my monitor as a built in display,and will not allow me to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install your propertier drivers for your graphics card ? incase you run a nvidia gpu here's a link to linux driver download. [gpu](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-archive.html)

Comment: Thanks, However when i click on the , run file, gedit keeps crashing.